# Adding a popup Menu to a tree in e4 Rcp

Tags: e4, tableviewer

I am creating a tree structure in RCP application. I want to able to create a pop up menu. I have been able to create a dummy menu item.

```java
 final Menu treeMenu = new Menu(check.getShell(), SWT.POP_UP);
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(treeMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setText("Open");
        item.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("CAme in Open");
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        check.setMenu(treeMenu);
```

this menu however does not recognize the node details. I want something that can obtain information about the node which we have opened context menu on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `TreeViewer` (or `TableViewer`) just get the current selection:

```java
IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection)treeViewer.getSelection();

Object selectedElement = sel.getFirstElement();
```

For a `Tree` use:

```
TreeItem [] selectedItems = tree.getSelection();
```

Comment: can we add this directly inside the widgetselected method?

Comment: Yes. Obviously you have to make the treeViewer available

Comment: that is something that I will try but is there something we can do if we are using tree instead if treeviewer